# Incoming calls are identified as coming from Mexico incorrectly by area code?

Tags: lock-screens, verizon, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I have a Verizon Galaxy S8 and I was traveling in Mexico a couple weeks ago, and when I came back, all incoming calls are saying `Mexico` on the screen.

As far as I know, I don't have any special apps on the phone identifying caller info, but it's just using the area code.

Any idea where to go to fix this?

**Edit:** Here's an image:

[image]

Comment: Where does it say Mexico? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Next incoming call I get, I'll try. It shows it right on the lock screen when you receive an incoming call. It's a stock thing. It's not Verizon's caller ID thing and it's not a special app.

Comment: @aBochur - I've added an image now

Comment: Strange indeed. You can try clearing data for the calling app. Go to settings>apps>in the menu, select *show system apps* > phone > storage > clear data. This should not delete any personal data, it will only refresh the calling app.

Comment: @aBochur I see 3 `Phone` icons that are all identical looking, but different sizes. I tried your steps for all 3. It doesn't do it for every call, but many of them. I'll wait for the next call and see.

Comment: @aBochur - It happened again and I have some interesting info. I received a call from a `972` number this time (says Mexico) and when I go to recent calls, it says `Oaxaca` instead of `Dallas`. If I go to `Phone>Settings>More Settings` , it has current country selected as `United States of America`. I clicked on it a couple times to try and "reselect" it or something. I think you are correct that the core of the issue is the `Phone` app somehow. I tried dialing `*228` to see if it was a Verizon thing too.